# Why is texture paint mirroring?

Tags: texture-painting

I uv mapped a part of my character and am looking to texture paint it. I used the fill brush to fill the whole part green, but then went to the texture draw brush and then drew on the back of the character. The drawing appeared, but it flipped to the front of the mesh. I applied the mirror modifier. The image shows the uvs of the object, and the stroke that I painted on the back of the mesh, but showed up on the front.[image]

Comment: Please test this.  Can you get 5 strokes to appear correctly on the front?  Can you get 5 strokes to appear correctly on the back?  What modifiers are active on the Mesh. Mirror Modifier?

Comment: Mirroring actually means that both sides would get painted (and also look identically) which is obviously not the case. My guess is that you just assume what your front and your back in the UV image editor is. I think that the UV part which you assume is the back of the mesh is actually the front of it.

Comment: @metaphor_set Ok I tried selecting the uvs and rotating (r-y-180) and the problem was still there

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger There is no mirror, just sub-surface, and I can't get any strokes successfully on with painting on the side I want the stroke to appear on.

Comment: I didn't say anything about rotating. You say you want to paint on the back but the strokes apear on the front. Where do you actually paint? 3D view or UV texture editor? Maybe you could upload your blend file to blend exchange, so we could take a closer look?

Comment: @metaphor_set Here is the blender file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByrMQl4A3FTwbWViVjBaSXM4Zzg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Its overlapping uv on each other. Separate the uv's

Answer (score 1):

Your normals are inverted (they are going inside the model).
Texture paint paints on front normals. That's why when you think you paint the front, all is going to the back.
To see the normals (edit mode) : go to the "mesh display" part of the right panel of the 3D view.
To inverse the normals, select all the needed vertices, then ctrl+N or ctrl+shift+N.